# Parser question, How can I get my int value from list

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup

I do

```
games = html.findAll(class_ = "kv")
```

and got list of different values. How can I get my int value `"Матчі"`?

This is example what I have

```
[<div class="kv">All Pick<small>Найбільш популярний режим</small></div>, <div class="kv">Рейтинговий пошук матчів<small>Найбільш популярне лоббі</small></div>, <div class="kv">Центральна лінія<small>Найчастіша лінія</small></div>, <div class="kv">Роль Головна<small>Найбільш поширені ролі</small></div>, <div class="kv">10,598<small>Матчі</small></div>, <div class="kv">36:25<small>Тривалість матчу</small></div>, <div class="kv"><span 
class="color-stat-win">53.09%</span><small>Відсоток перемог</small></div>, <div class="kv"><span class="color-stat-kda">3.6</span><small>Співвідношення УСП</small></div>,]
```

I need to get my 10,598 value from all this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `<small>` tag with `text="Матчі"` and then get previous node:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<div class="kv">All Pick<small>Найбільш популярний режим</small></div>
<div class="kv">Рейтинговий пошук матчів<small>Найбільш популярне лоббі</small></div>
<div class="kv">Центральна лінія<small>Найчастіша лінія</small></div>
<div class="kv">Роль Головна<small>Найбільш поширені ролі</small></div>
<div class="kv">10,598<small>Матчі</small></div>
<div class="kv">36:25<small>Тривалість матчу</small></div>
<div class="kv"><span class="color-stat-win">53.09%</span><small>Відсоток перемог</small></div>
<div class="kv"><span class="color-stat-kda">3.6</span><small>Співвідношення УСП</small></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

value = soup.find("small", text="Матчі").previous
print(value)
```

Prints:

```
10,598
```

---

EDIT: To get value from `title=`:

```py
html_doc = """
<div class="rank-tier-wrapper" rel="tooltip" title="Ранг: ВартовийIV">
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
print(soup.find(class_="rank-tier-wrapper")["title"])
```

Prints:

```
Ранг: ВартовийIV
```

Comment: yo, thanks. But I have another question. How from class get constant value? 

I want to find ` tittle = ` in
<div class="rank-tier-wrapper" rel="tooltip" title="Ранг: ВартовийIV">

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to search for the DIV containing `Матчі`, and then extract the number at the beginning.

```
import re

games = html.find(class_ = 'kv', text = re.compile('Матчі'))
if games:
    game_count = re.match(r'^[\d,]+', games.string).group(0)
```